# NameError: name 'home' is not defined

Tags: python, variables

Im writing a text game and all other parts of my code are working i think but ive been trying to figure out why my variable isnt defined.
I could be missing something simple but i just cant find it.The problem is under def aussie().
Ive tried changing indents, changing variable name and checking for " or () missing/

```
def aussie():
    home= input("""
'Where are you from? it'd be better off taking you home than you travelling with us
A)Ortus
B)...""")
    if "A" in home: 
      print("""
Eugene says 'How the hell did you end up out here then?You know what doesnt matter'
They take you back home to Ortus.
You Win""")
start()
if "B" in home:
     print("""
Eugene says 'Right then guess your coming back to Australia with us!'
You live happily ever after with Eugene
You Win?!""")
start()

def boat():
    h= input("How will you get help?")
    if "swim" in h:
        print("""
 The boat goes right past you leaving you stranded.
 You Lose""")
        start()
    if "shout" in h:
        print("""
One of the crew members hear you and shout orders to slow the boat.You notice he has a
very strong Australian accent. The crew help you onto the boat wrapping you in towels
and blankets before sitting you at a table.You are in a state of shock.
        
You try to stand up but feel nauseous and dizzy.You fall to the floor with a thud.
The same Australian man rushes in and props you up against a wall before sitting next
to you on the floor.He sits for a while and chats to you letting you know his name is Eugene.
When you feel better he asks,""")
aussie()


 
start()
direct()
```

Comment: You having strings on multiple lines like that makes it very hard to keep track on your indentation. Consider using `\n` in your string instead of an actual newline, or create global variables at the top of the program containing the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong.  You must be very careful with indentation in Python  Because `start()` is in column 1, it is no longer considered part of the function.  It will be executed immediately.  You might consider storing your very long strings in a global array up at the top, to make the indentation more obvious.

And, by the way, if `start` ends up calling `aussie` or `boat`, then you have recursion going on.  That is NOT a good way to design something like this.  These functions should return True or False telling the caller whether they should loop around again or exit.